# How to produce N nouns that have a specific suffix, using Spacy?

Tags: spacy

I would like to generate a relatively random list of 20 nouns which all have the same ending, using Spacy. In my case, the language is German, and an example ending could be “-keit”.

I believe that Spacy has a large list of words in `nlp.vocab` for each language within the package, but if I iterate over it, I don’t know if the order will be random or identical for each run.

I know that Spacy also has a `Corpus` object, and I’m wondering if that supports methods more suitable for searching for particular examples of a specific linguistic form.

If `NLP.Vocab` is not a comprehensive word-list over a given language, is there a dataset commonly used in the Spacy universe to load in that contains a complete vocabulary?

Answer (score 0):

Every language model in Spacy has default vocabulary within it:

```
nlp = spacy.load(“en_core_web_sm”) # of type Language - https://spacy.io/api/language/

vocab = nlp.vocab # of type Vocab - https://spacy.io/api/vocab
```

You can obtain the `Lexeme` object for any word by indexing the `Vocab` object with that word as a string:

```
word = nlp.vocab[“apple”]
```

You can iterate over the `Vocab` object to collect N words that are nouns and end with the particular suffix.

If you want the words to be picked from random, you could use random choice.

The Spacy `Corpus` object is for loading in data that is to be used for training new pipelines, so it doesn’t have the features described above.

The larger models have more vectors so they probably have bigger vocabularies. For English that would be [`en_core_web_lg`](https://spacy.io/models/en).

Answer (score 0):

The Vocab object in a pipeline is made to handle certain data structures with information about Lexemes, and is not intended as a useful list of words. The words in the Vocab are not a list of all words in the language, but rather every word the model has seen - so that includes strings for internal use (like "NOUN") or typos in the training corpus, but not uncommon words that happen to not be in the corpus. You can read more about what the Vocab is [in the dev docs](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/extra/DEVELOPER_DOCS/StringStore-Vocab.md).

spaCy doesn't have features for language generation ([it's specifically out of scope](https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures#comparison-usage)), so you're probably better off finding a word list elsewhere and using that as your source.

As an exception, for some languages spaCy has large lists of words by part of speech as data for the lemmatizer, which are kept in [spacy-lookups-data](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-lookups-data). It depends a lot on the language, but these are often intended to be comprehensive. For German there is a list of words, but not one organized by parts of speech.